# flatpickr js keeps reverting date to Jan 1, 2022

Tags: javascript, datepicker, flatpickr

I'm using [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) as a datepicker in html/js. I pull the module in using jsdelivr:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
```

It's been behaving normally for years, but yesterday it started behaving oddly. Here is my javascript, which I have not changed:

```
$("input[type='datetime'], input[type='datetime-local']").flatpickr({
        enableTime: true,
          altInput: true,
          altFormat: "F j, Y at h:i K",
          dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
        time_24hr: false
      });
```

And that displays a datepicker like so:
[image: source code]

When I select a date, the value of the `datepicker flatpickr-input` class changes to the datetime chosen and the `datepicker form-control input` class changes its name to `datepicker form-control input active`. I think that's all expected.

The problem is that when I click a second time (either on another date or outside of the calendar div), the datetime removes my selection and replaces it with `2022-01-01 00:00`.

Why is it doing that rather than keeping the value I select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a similar issue, looks like it's with the latest version of 4.6.10.  Reverting to 4.6.9 seems to fix the issue.

More here:

https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/issues/2655

Comment: FYI, looks like the latest version of 4.6.11 fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the Django framework, so running `collectstatic` updated my flatpickr version. For future reference -- how do I specify a version using jsdelivr?